# Has image base address optimization sense?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, linker

There is technique which allows to reduce loading time of dlls (it was mentioned by Jeffrey Richter). The base idea to choose properly image base addresses of dlls. It allows to avoid conflicts of loading different libraries at the same addresses (some additional rebasing is not used). So, I decided to see default settings provided by `msvc linker`. It turns out that linker uses randomized base addresses (`/DYNAMICBASE` option) by default. This way allows to solve vulnerability issues. Such feature (`address space layout randomization`) was introduced by `windows` since `vista` generation. So, as I understand it is preferred way to link `Dlls` on modern os (windows 10 for example). Setting image base address will lead to potential security weakness. Has image base address optimization sense in such case? Or maybe is it deprecated? <s>Were there similar rebasing issues for randomized addresses for `dlls`? For example loading different `dlls` at the same address?</s>

Comment: *was mentioned by Jeffrey Richter* - almost 20 years ago. this already not actual after *ASLR*.  *Setting image base address will lead* - no. you **always** set same base address to *PE*. *loading different dlls at the some address?* - what you mean here ? really all what you need - have relocation and `/DYNAMICBASE` and [`/HIGHENTROPYVA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/highentropyva-support-64-bit-aslr?view=vs-2019) options. all

Comment: @RbMm, thanks for reply. My last questions don't have sense. I understood it. Yes, you are right. Book is really old. It seems like it deprecated now

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=95225